# The value keeps being replaced by the loop

Tags: c#, json

The problem I am facing is thst the `json[]` will keep being replaced with new value.
What I want to achieve is to store all the values.
I have tried `json[index][xxx]` but it's still not working.

```cs
var json = new JObject();
for(int index = 0; index < employeeCareerProgression.Count; index++)
{
    json["Desc"] = employeeCareerProgression[index].Description;
    json["Date"] = employeeCareerProgression[index].ProgressionStartDate;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit large piece of code would help. But it seems like you always set the Object json["desc"]/ json["date"] with a certain piece of information. json["desc"] will always be overwritten. You have to sort out what exactly you want to have set. What exactly is json[]

Comment: I replaced your image of code with **code**, but as Nico pointed out, it would help if you add the declaration and initialization of `json`

Comment: @NicoWalsemann i already updated the code. Yes as you mention it will always be overwritten. I finding a way to make it but unsuccessful.

Comment: @Rafalon Thanks man. I already updated it.

Comment: What is wrong with the `json[index]["Desc"]` approach? Do you have an error message or something else?

Comment: He doesnt do the [index][desc] approach, if he would do that it dfntly would work. But he does json["desc"] and the setted value is the one of the Index. Still it only updates the main one. the approach from @MrSuttonmann would work or indicating through the jsonObject would be a way too.

Comment: @Rafalon I did get this exception "Accessed JObject values with invalid key value:0. Object property name expected. "

Comment: @NicoWalsemann OP said in the question "I have tried `json[index][xxx]` but still not working"

Comment: @Rafalon thats basicly because his jsonObject is not a Collection (would be fixable) but still the answer from MrSuttonmann does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have to add a new JProperty to your JObject - you're setting a new value to the same property on every loop.

Try this, it might work for you. I've not tested it however.

```
var json = new JObject();
for(var index = 0; index < employeeCareerProgression.Count; index++)
{
  json.Add(new JProperty(index, // You could change this index to a more descriptive field on your employeeCareerProgression object (maybe the primary key, or employee name?)
    new JObject
    {
      new JProperty("Desc", employeeCareerProgression[index].Description),
      new JProperty("Date", employeeCareerProgression[index].ProgressionStartDate),
    }
  );
}
```

You should end up with a JSON like this:

```json
{[
  '0': {
     'Desc': 'DESCRIPTION',
     'Date': '2020-12-14T00:00:00Z'
  }, 
  '1': {
     ...
  }
]}
```

Comment: Can you really add a property named `"Desc"` (or `"Date"`) several times to a same `JObject`? I quite doubt that

Comment: @Rafalon No, probably not. I realise my mistake and I've edited my code to fix that.

Comment: @MrSuttonmann Thanks! It worked! The index need to add .ToString() and it will work.

Comment: @jayDD2 Depending on what you're using that JSON for, I wouldn't recommend using the index as the key for each JSON object. If you have something else, like some unique identifier for each `employeeCareerProgression`, that would be a better choice.